# tizen tv logs - how to access them?

Tags: javascript, tizen, smart-tv

official tutorials from Samsung seem to be bad, since, they say, samsung device logs should be available by default. However, while using CLI, I had little success. 
Since I am using react to create tizen web application, it is not possible to use tizen studio, because it fails to compile JS bigger than 1MB or so.
Therefore I am left to use only CLI tools. I managed to push my app to my TV using commands:

tizen build-web -- build/
tizen package -t wgt -s $PROFILE -- build
tizen install -s $TARGET --name Demo.wgt -- build/
tizen run -s $TARGET -p nULpxYMX3f.Demo

But what now? How can I access some web console or other logs? I already tried:

sdb dlog
closed
- waiting for device -

connecting via browser using remote web inspector with my tvs IP and port 7011 - page not found

Am I doing something wrong? How do you access logs when testing on real device? Or even emulator, since it behaves the same.

Comment: Try to re-connect sdb. `sdb connect <target ip>` and `sdb dlog <log tag>`

Comment: I tried `sdb connect 10.0.2.15:26101` (IP is taken from tv -> settings -> network and port is default 26101. not sure, is that port is correct), but with error message `error: failed to connect to remote target '10.0.2.15'`

Comment: Did you activate development mode? Check below link. https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/smart-view-sdk/receiver-apps/debugging